# Meteor User Accounts Social Network Buttons Not Displaying

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

m a newbie using meteor. I created an app and followed the [guide](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md#quickstart) by running the following commands:

```
-meteor add useraccounts:materialize
-meteor add materialize:materialize
-meteor add accounts-password
-meteor add accounts-facebook
-meteor add accounts....
```

After creating a template with the line {{> atForm}} and running the app i noticed that it never shows the external login buttons, from facebook and etc as it should. only the form for local login. It only shows the email and passord field for local authentication.

I've also tried with bootstrap and it doesn't works.

Any clues on what may be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the packages folder gets conflicts.

You could try uninstalling all accounts packages (check .packages file). Make sure you remove accounts-ui packages, then try again with your setup. Also remove autopublish and insecure.

Ultimately a fresh install with above steps will probably fix if nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

It was missing the configuration

Ex: [Login With Facebook Using Meteor](http://bulenttastan.net/login-with-facebook-using-meteor-js/)